# Linking Data between Simulink and Blender

Tags: python, hyperlink, simulink, blender

I've been trying to determine a way to link data between a running Simulink model and Blender (or Python).  I have no idea where to start on this, but I did find one piece of software that might've solved it, if I could get it to install correct; SimServer.

I found out about SimServer on StackOverflow (the original question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198488/access-call-simulink-from-python)), however I cannot get it to install correctly, it errors out during mex in the httpwrapper.c file stating that "syntax error; found `SOCKET' expecting`}'" (same if I remove the httpwrapper.c file from the mex command, it'll error out on another file the same way).

Is there a way to remedy this, or should I move on and try to find another solution?  I feel as if another solution would be preferable and probably easier to install onto other machines.  Is there someway I can pipe information from a running Simulink model to a file and have Blender/Python watch that file for changes and update a model in Blender Game in real-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in writing data to a file from Simulink there are several ways to do that. I think the Easiest way would be to use add_exec_event_listener to add a callback listening to 'PostOutputs' event of your block. Within this callback you access data from block and write to a file.

You can find doc for add_exec_event_listener at http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/add_exec_event_listener.html

Other ways to write to file from Simulink are

1. Using MATLAB Function block. Use your own "extrinsic" function to write to file.
2. Write S-Function in MATLAB or C/C++.

From the external program you can watch this file for updates. Having real-time in this approach is doubtful. There could be lags in writing to file in disk and for the other program to notice the changes.

Comment: I actually was able to get them to talk to each other by dumping Simulink data (via the MATLAB function block) to a file and having Blender just read it on each update, but I can get that up to about 10 fps (which is fine for my purposes and is only due to the model complexity).

However, I am curious about trying to take on a TCP/IP or UDP approach to this problem, as Simulink and Blender might be running on two different machines.  I think this might ultimately be a better approach, but I wouldn't mind any criticism or suggestions.

Comment: If you would like to try UDP, DSP System toolbox has UDP send and receive blocks.

Comment: Yep, I've got that in place.  I just need to setup a UDP server in Blender and it should be good to go.  Thanks!